# FCOE between virtual chassis Juniper EX and Cisco Nexus

Tags: cisco, juniper, fcoe, san

Is it possible to connect an server with FCOE adapter  on a virtual chassis juniper ex4550 in order to access a fc disk array connected to a Cisco Nexus 5548UP?

The juniper and the nexus are connected together with 10G optic cable.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible, although Juniper's documentation is very vague.

It is my understanding that in order to do FCoE, the EX4550 must be a stand-alone device, not part of a Virtual-Chassis.

There is vague reference in the EX4600 doco that says:

```
 Note: Standalone switches support FCoE. Virtual Chassis (VC) and mixed-    
 mode Virtual Chassis Fabric (VCF) configurations do not support FCoE.    
 Pure QFX5100 switch VCFs (consisting of only QFX5100 switches) support FCoE.
```

This can be found at the following URL:

http://www.jnpr.net/techpubs/en_US/junos13.2/topics/concept/fibre-channel-fcoe-understanding.html

You could test on a dummy VLAN on your EX-VC by trying to commit the following and see what happens:

```
ethernet-switching-options {
    secure-access-port {
        interface xe-0/0/0.0 {
            fcoe-trusted;
        }
        vlan my-fcoe-vlan {
            examine-fip {
                fc-map 0x0EFC03;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We have a problem with dcbx exchange between juniper and cisco, the status on juniper stay at in-sync.